# Подсветка вложенных скобок

Tags: python, pyqt5

Есть текст со вложенными скобками `текст1(текст2(текст3))`, глубина вложенности скобок - произвольная, нужно сделать так (не нашел, как подсветить текст здесь) чтобы текст1 был одного цвета, текст2 с внешними скобками - другого и текст3 с внутренними скобками - третьего цвета. Сделать нужно на PyQt. В сети нашел пример и подправив его, получил подсветку только внешних скобок и то что в них.

```
class MyHighlighter(QSyntaxHighlighter):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.regexp_by_format = dict()

        char_format = QTextCharFormat()
        char_format.setFontWeight(QFont.Bold)
        char_format.setForeground(Qt.darkRed)
        self.regexp_by_format[r'\((.*)\)'] = char_format

    def highlightBlock(self, text):
        for regexp, char_format in self.regexp_by_format.items():
            expression = QRegularExpression(regexp)
            it = expression.globalMatch(text)
            while it.hasNext():
                match = it.next()
                self.setFormat(match.capturedStart(), match.capturedLength(), char_format)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mw = QTextEdit()
    mw.setText("text(text(text(text)))")
    highlighter = MyHighlighter(mw.document())    
    mw.show()
```

Как сделать, чтобы было, как мне нужно? Спасибо.

Comment: опубликуйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример,  который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Тю, задача написать "парсер ЯП Lisp" на Python. Делается за вечер :) (Воспринимайте как набор ключевых слов для поиска решения самостоятельно)

Comment: тем не менее у меня получилось решить, публикую ответ

Comment: Это регулярками не делается.

Comment: @Евгений, получилось? Вопрос: _"глубина вложенности скобок - произвольная",_ ответ: _"Для 4-й глубины вложенности"._

Comment: Согласен, непроизвольная, это была неточность вопроса.

Comment: Но вообще, регулярное выражение в шаблоне можно сгенерировать  для произвольной глубины, мне кажется.

Answer (score 3):

Для 4-й глубины вложенности, класс должен выглядеть следующим образом:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MyHighlighter(QSyntaxHighlighter):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.regexp_by_format = dict()

        char_format = QTextCharFormat()
        char_format.setFontWeight(QFont.Bold)
        char_format.setForeground(Qt.green)
        self.regexp_by_format[r'\([^()]*\([^()]*\([^()]*\)[^()]*\)[^()]*\)'] = char_format

        char_format = QTextCharFormat()
        char_format.setFontWeight(QFont.Bold)
        char_format.setForeground(Qt.blue)
        self.regexp_by_format[r'\([^()]*\([^()]*\)[^()]*\)'] = char_format

        char_format = QTextCharFormat()
        char_format.setFontWeight(QFont.Bold)
        char_format.setForeground(Qt.red)
        self.regexp_by_format[r'\([^()]*\)'] = char_format

    def highlightBlock(self, text):
        for regexp, char_format in self.regexp_by_format.items():
            expression = QRegularExpression(regexp)
            it = expression.globalMatch(text)
            while it.hasNext():
                match = it.next()
                self.setFormat(match.capturedStart(), match.capturedLength(), char_format)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 14, QFont.Bold))
    mw = QTextEdit()
    mw.setText("text(text(text(text)))")
    highlighter = MyHighlighter(mw.document())    
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Если ничего не напутал - должно работать.

Да, есть неточность, несколько скобок одной глубины работают неправильно,  надо подправить регулярки:

```
r'\([^()]*(\([^()]*(\([^()]*\))*[^()]*\))*[^()]*\)'
r'\([^()]*(\([^()]*\))*[^()]*\)'
r'\([^()]*\)'
```

Comment: да, ваш пример работает правильно.